# Children's telefilm about a handicapped girl's beliefs in fairytale characters

Tags: story-identification, movie

**Genre**: Children's fantasy

**Story**:

- **Start**: Main lead is a girl who believes in fairytale characters, like a fairy from the story Cinderella or Pinocchio etc. They all visit her when nobody is around but vanish if anybody comes. They play with her and cheer her up when she is low.
- **Middle**: Her friends start giving her doubts that it is true, instead it's all made up by her brain. Also, her family had the same beliefs. She forces the magical creature to stay so that she can show them to her friends and they agreed but when she brings them nobody was there.  The fairy gives some explanation that why it's not possible for them to reveal themselves to everyone like this.
- **End**: Either she was always not able to walk from the start or loses the ability later. The doctor said she can't walk ever. She is depressed and tells the fairy if she really has any magic then help her walk.  The fairy holds her hand and tells her to walk and she starts walking. She later shows this to her family and they are very happy but still don't believe in fairytales.  They think it's her beliefs which made the impossible possible.

**Broadcast channel:**  [Doordarshan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doordarshan) (DD1)

**Broadcast year:** the Mid-90s

**Format:** Colour telefilm

**Language:** Hindi

**Country:** India